# How to change the "-" sign into pipe sign "|" in WordPress title?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the WordPress title separator sign (-) into pipe sign (|). Can anyone tell how to do this?

[image]

Comment: <title><?php wp_title('|', true); ?></title> replace this in header.php

Answer (score 1):

To replace the '-' with '|' you can follow the below steps :

1. Find remove `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` (it may be in functions.php `after_setup_theme` hook )
2. add `<title><?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?></title>` in header.php
3. For setting `POST_NAME | BLOG_NAME`, this one line code should be great `<?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>`

To know more visit the [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)